# Hyperlink in email on mobile only with CSS3

Tags: css, hyperlink, html-email

I am looking to add a hyperlink in a HTML email but only on mobile through CSS3. Is there any CSS3 property to do that?

Comment: No, there isn't: CSS affects, and *effects*, *only* the presentation, it cannot change the HTML mark-up, or provide functionality.

Comment: In fact you can change a lot of markup in emails for mobile through CSS3. e.g. before & after CSS3 property to add/remove copy on mobile and so on so forth. I'm not sure who put negative votes on this, kind of pissing me off.

Comment: No, you can't: the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements are not in the mark-up, they're not available in the DOM. Converting text into a link is impossible with CSS (CSS cannot directly target specific text (except for the `::first-letter`, `::first-line` pseudo-elements) without that text being wrapped in a tag of some kind). Mobile can show/hide links (with media-queries, for example), but it *cannot* create them.

Comment: @DiNovici As you know from your comment to me, Gmail won't respect your before/after CSS. HTML e-mail barely understands CSS, let alone CSS**3**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible via CSS.

You have a couple options:

- Something like `<span class="mobile"><a href="the link">The link</a></span><span class="desktop">No link</span>` plus a `@media` query to show/hide the two spans on different device sizes.
- Style the link on desktop via a `@media` query so it looks like normal text (i.e. `color: #000; cursor: default; text-decoration: none;`)

Comment: thanks, but this is an email, I forgot to specify that. Gmail is stripping out all head style and to make things worst doesn't work also with display:none.

Comment: There's not anything that'll do the trick in Gmail, to my knowledge. Gmail lacks a wide variety of CSS options. http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 2):

ceejayoz is pretty close. You just have to reverse your thinking a little bit.

If you're only putting the hyperlink on mobile/smaller screens this can be done easily with inline css and an `@media` query in the `<head>`. (Note. I would recommend sending the emails through an Email Service Provider to make sure your `@media` query remains untouched.)

This is the approach I would take.

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    a[class="link"] {
        font-size: 12px !important;
        color: #000001 !important;
        text-decoration: underline !important;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="http://yourlink.com" style="font-size: 1px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">yourlink.com</a>
```

I should also mention not all mobile email clients will recognize the `@media` query properly. Gmail on Android for example doesn't work very well when developing responsive HTML emails.

Comment: Thanks Darryl but this will leave a space where the white text is on desktops. What I finally did is adding the link for both but make the linked text on desktops black and removing the underline so it appears like a regular text while on mobile is a link.

Comment: Ahhh... I get ya. I didn't realize the text was there on both desktop and mobile, and only a link on mobile. Using the inline css to style it like regular text is a reasonable solution. Try adding a cursor style as well to protect your desktop clients from seeing the link even more.